# Custom flag box sticking out

Tags: bug, flags, design

This appears to be a bug that occurs when you try and report something with a custom flag:

[image: Custom flag box sticking out]

As you can probably see, the box is actually sticking out of its box. So I just thought that I should report this bug. If it is a bug and not just some weird design!

---

**OS Information:**

> Description: Ubuntu 14.10
>
> Release:     14.10

**Browser Information:**

> Google Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.118 (64-bit))
>
> PPA: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

Comment: OS? Browser? (With versions) Also, something similar was asked yesterday and it was a dup of something from long ago.

Comment: @MARamezani: Ok, I have added the requested information to my question.